# avoid span float right overlap with text (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css-float, rickshaw

I'm using rickshaw and have a graph hover/annotation where a colour swatch (defined using a `<span>` is overlapping with text within the `<div>` that they're both contained in.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="detail" style="left:250px">
    <div class="item active" style="top: 200px"> 
        <span style="background-color: #30c020" class="detail_swatch"></span>
        Very very very very very long label: 67<br/>
        <span style="color:#A0A0A0">Wed, 12 Feb 2014 18:51:01 GMT</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
.detail {
    position: absolute;
}
.detail .item {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0.25em;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.detail .item.active {
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.detail_swatch {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 4px 10px 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

The `detail_swatch` correctly displays in the upper right hand corner, but will overlap the `very very ... long label`. Most solutions I've read to this problem involve changing the position statement of the containing div. That's not an option.

Is there any way I can ensure the `detail_swatch` does not overlap the text, and instead expands the `div` they're contained in (horizontally)?

This code is available on JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KWt4C/), which also displays the problem.

Comment: Add padding then position `.detail_swatch` absolutely: http://jsfiddle.net/KWt4C/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `padding-left: 15px;` to the `.detail .item.active {}` to ensure that the item will not be overlapped by text. Then I made the `.detail_swatch` to be positioned absolute instead of `float: right;` so it overlaps the padding I added.

Here is the changed css:

```
.detail .item.active {
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.detail_swatch {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 4px 10px 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KWt4C/1/)

Fiddle with very very long text: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KWt4C/3/)

Comment: It is working for text having space or "dash" between there.
But how to avoid overlapping when there is no space or dash between the text.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the element at a fixed width you could use `text-overflow: ellipsis`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWt4C/5/)

```
.detail .text {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 90%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue is that span is an inline elemenent, it is meant to be shown inline. You want the span containing the date to behave like a block-level element, so your choice of element is wrong.

The solution is simple; use a divs instead of span to contain the date and remove the br.